# setTimeOut with pass one function as parameter

Tags: javascript

For a webForm I [need a custom trigger](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/advanced-use-of-the-jira-issue-collector-788726105.html#AdvanceduseoftheJiraissuecollector-Addingthecustomtriggerfunctionmanually) for a function that is called automatically **after the page is loaded**. I have a working example, but the problem is that the id `triggerIDCanChange` can change. So I need a way without using `triggerIDCanChange`.

```
window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS = $.extend(window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS, {

    triggerFunction : setTimeout(function() {
        $('#triggerIDCanChange').trigger('click');
        //showCollectorDialog(); // not defined
        }, 100)
});
```

Another working example is here, where a parameter `showCollectorDialog` is passed to the triggerFunction. However, the problem here is that the function is not called automatically via setTimeout. So I would need to click on the element with id 'button1' to trigger the function call.

```
window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS = $.extend(window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS, {
    triggerFunction : function( showCollectorDialog ) {
        $('#button1').on( 'click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            showCollectorDialog();
        });
    }
});
```

I have looked in the documentation of setTimeout and have seen that I can pass parameters. But also this example is not working. Reference error showCollectorDialog is not defined. I assume this is caused because the triggerFunction needs to have the form function ( parameter ). So, do you have any other ideas how to call `showCollectorDialog()`after the page is loaded?

```
...
triggerFunction : setTimeout(function() {
    showCollectorDialog();
    }, 100, showCollectorDialog) // error: showCollectorDialog not defined
...
```

Comment: If the id can change, can you give it a class that does not change?

Comment: If you're passing an argument to the function, the function needs to use a parameter: `function(param) { param(); }`

Comment: But if the function isn't defined, it doesn't matter whether you call it directly or pass it as a parameter. Where is that function supposed to come from?

Comment: I cannot set a custom class for the default button. But when I create another new button then yes. Everything is fixed (loaded from an external source). I can only set the triggerFunction manually.

Comment: @Barmar Parameter is coming from an externally JS. See https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/advanced-use-of-the-jira-issue-collector-788726105.html

Comment: Are you loading a library asynchronously, and it's going to define the function? You should run your code in the library's `load` event listener rather than using `setTimeout()`.

Comment: I can not directly access the function. The function is just passed to the triggerFunction that I can manually provide. The triggerFunction must be in the format ‘function ( parameter )‘.

Comment: Do you also want to set a `click` listener to a button etc. or do you just want to call `showCollectorDialog` after a timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
triggerFunction: function (showCollectorDialog) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    showCollectorDialog();
  }, 100);
}
```

Also, the link provided in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61964627/settimeout-with-pass-one-function-as-parameter#comment109596044_61964627) says that:

> The `triggerFunction` will be invoked by the issue collector after the `$(document).ready()` phase.

So if the time until `$(document).ready()` phase (which at least after the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired, see the relevant [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) for more details) is enough for you then you can simply write:

```
triggerFunction: function (showCollectorDialog) {
  showCollectorDialog();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Unfortunately neither the first nor the second solution opens the showCollectorDialog.

Comment: Sorry, since I couldn't test it I thought the problem was a matter of accessing a variable in from a particular scope. Anyway, can you see any errors in browser's console?

Comment: Thank you, the first solution with the delay works! There was an error in the settings of the form. I had to enable the custom trigger possibility!